# Is there a feature that can add row spacing as print.default does for columns

Tags: r, format

I was wondering if there is a way to add padding between rows, the same way
print.default do to rows, or maybe with different frequency, like adding an empty row (or some space) every 3 rows.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(25),5,5, dimnames = list(paste0("row",1:5), paste0("row",1:5)))
print(mat) 
print.default(mat, print.gap = 5)
```

Also, is there a way to manipulate positioning as you do with format?

```
print.default(format(mat, width = 15), quote = FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function which adds an empty row. But note that this would be just for printing purposes. Below function should get you started.

```
rowSpaces <- function(x, chunk = 2, digits = 3) {
  x <- round(x, digits)

  emptyrow <- rep("", ncol(x))
  nrows <- nrow(x)
  indices <- split(1:nrows, ceiling(seq_along(1:nrows)/chunk))

  inserted <- sapply(indices, FUN = function(m) c(m + 1, 1))
  inserted <- do.call(c, inserted)
  xy <- rbind(emptyrow, x)
  out <- xy[inserted, ]
  rownames(out) <- gsub("emptyrow", "", rownames(out))
  out
}

print(rowSpaces(mat, chunk = 2), quote = FALSE)

     row1   row2  row3   row4   row5 
row1 -0.47  1.076 -0.551 -0.091 0.478
row2 1.058  0.384 -1.138 -0.155 0.031

row3 -0.825 -0.43 -0.105 -1.658 0.078
row4 -0.282 0.037 -0.567 -0.317 0.65 

row5 -1.209 1.262 -1.116 0.529  2.18
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for, but still a handy function. I think the part `inserted<- do.call(c, inserted)` is not needed!